# How to create a custom router with url key

Tags: magento2, custom, routing, url-key

I'm looking to create a custom router so that if I go to `www.mysite.com/promotions/cruise-trip` it would route to `www.mysite/offers/promotions/index/id/5` for example. I'm not really sure how to do this though. I currently have the following set up:

### etc/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="offers" id="offers">
            <module name="Hurdo_Offers"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

### etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customrouter" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Hurdo\Promotions\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

### Hurdo/Promotions/Controller/Router.php

```
<?php
namespace Hurdo\Promotions\Controller;

use \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;

    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    public function match(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if (strpos($identifier, 'promotions') !== false) {
            $request->setModuleName('offers')-> //module name
                setControllerName('promotions')-> //controller name
                setActionName('index')-> //action name
                setParam('id', 5); //custom parameters
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
            ['request' => $request]
        );
    }
}
```

But I've no idea how to get this to work with a url key such as `cruise-trip` etc.
Thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace below code with your router file according to your url-key.

```
<?php
namespace Hurdo\Promotions\Controller;

use \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;

    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    public function match(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $id = '';
        if (strpos($identifier, 'promotions') !== false) {

            $finalKey = explode('/', $identifier);
            $urlKey = end($finalKey);

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $offerModel = $objectManager->get('Namespace\Vendor\Model\Offers')->load($urlKey,'url-key');
            if($offerModel->getId() {
                $id = $offerModel->getId();
            }

            if($id) {
                $request->setModuleName('offers')-> //module name
                    setControllerName('promotions')-> //controller name
                    setActionName('index')-> //action name
                    setParam('id', $id); //custom parameters
            } 
        }else {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
            ['request' => $request]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ZealousWeb. Hmm, it's still not working as expected.
Just to give a little bit more detail, I have a model set up called `Offer`. Each instance of this has an `id` as well as a `url-key` parameter. So what I'm looking for, is when I search for `www.mysite.com/promotions/cruise-trip`, it would set the information for the Cruise Trip object matching with id `5` and url-key `cruise-trip` in the database. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: If you want like this then you need to get parameter id in your block or template file then you need to filter by id in your custom collection.

Comment: that's the issue at the moment, I want the user who enters `www.mysite.com/promotion/cruise-ship` to be taken to the `mysqite.com/offers/promotions/id/5` at which point in my template, I could get the id parameter to load the relevant information for the cruise ship offer with id `5` etc. I just need to know how to process the end of a Url like `/promotions/cruise-ship` or `promotions/five-star-hotel` so that it knows whether to load information for the cruise ship offer, or the 5 star hotel offer for example.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You need to filter according to your id and your url key in your collection to load correct information.

Comment: Processing the ID isn't a problem once it reaches the template stage, I'm fine with that :) 
but how do I detect which ID to send based on the `cruise-ship` part at the end of the url? as currently there is no id being set in the request at that point.

Comment: Is your url-key unique? Am i right?

Comment: that's correct yes

Comment: OK then give me a minute please

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know on this

Comment: very nearly there but I want to check based on what the Url has at the end, i.e. I don't want to specifically search for the url key `cruise-ship` as there will likely be 100+ other offers added at some point. What I need to do is instead of checking for a specific url key, instead check which url key is added to the end, which could be either `cruise-ship`, `new-car`, `five-star-hotel`, `food-discounts` etc etc. 

So as you can see, it wouldn't be ideal to search for the specific url key in the code using `if (strpos($identifier, 'cruise-trip') !== false) {` and so on.

Comment: Edited my answer again. We don't need to put condition in your case.

Comment: Ah that looks more like it, thank you :) I'll give this a quick test now and I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120993/discussion-between-zealousweb-and-snafu).

Comment: Your answer has resolved this @ZealousWeb, thanks again for your help man :) 
I really need to double check that my `di.xml` is in `etc/frontend` instead of `/etc` in future :D